# dc.js error: d3.time is undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm having a problem when importing the d3.js and dc.js libraries. I import them in the right order, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: d3.time is undefined  utils.js:8
ReferenceError: dc is not defined
```

Here you can chek that I'm importing it in the right order:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "dc/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "dc/crossfilter/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "dc/dc/dc.js"></script>
```

That's the only code that I have right now, and I'm getting the error.

I'm using D3.js v4.11.0 and dc.js 2.4.1.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: dc.js is not yet compatible with d3v4. Please use d3 3.5.17. If you need to use both in the same application, you can rename one or the other, or use AMD to load d3v3 with dc.js. [I hope to make the port this year](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1173) however it's a pretty large effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where these files are sourced from and what the actual version is, and not familiar with the project file (route) structure, and also, the `dc.js` page says: `This page is running version: v2.1.8. The latest stable version is v2.0.2.` So not sure what branch or fork is at 2.4.1.

Having said that, a good approach is to take something that works and iterate on that. For example, [this page](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/vc/index.html) loads all the needed things. Also check version compatibility; eg. the above `dc.js` example uses `d3 v3.*`